# Why is UV radiation below 200nm strongly absorbed by Oxygen?

Tags: photons, absorption, electromagnetic-radiation

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet#Subtypes Ultraviolet radiation below $200$ nm is considered to be Vacuum Ultraviolet, due to being strongly absorbed by atmospheric Oxygen.

However I looked here https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/oxygentable2.htm ,
and there are no emission lines there between $131$ nm and $244$ nm.
So what's the cause of atmospheric absorption of $< 200$ nm UV?

Comment: Oxygen molecules photodissociate to oxygen atoms and those are involved in the ozone cycle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_depletion.

Comment: @EdV should have been an answer, not a comment - the spoils go to Rennie again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule we see discrete energy levels in bound states and continuous energy levels in unbound states. So if a transition is from one bound state to another we will see a sharp line, but if it is from a bound state to a free state we will see a broad absorption peak with a sharp low energy cutoff.

To take a simple example consider a hydrogen atom. The transition from the $1s$ to $2p$ is a transition between two bound states so we get a sharp line corresponding to the energy difference of $10.2\textrm{eV}$ between the two states.

But we know that the ionisation energy of hydrogen is $13.6\textrm{eV}$ so any energies higher than this produce free electron, and the energy of that free electron is not quantised. So the atom can absorb a $13.7\textrm{eV}$ photon to produce a free electron with a kinetic energy of $0.1\textrm{eV}$, or a $13.8\textrm{eV}$ to produce a free electron with an energy of $0.2\textrm{eV}$, and so on. So if we look at the hydrogen absorption spectrum at energies of $13.6\textrm{eV}$ and above we will see a broad absorption peak not a sharp line.

And this is what happens with oxygen molecules. The dissociation energy of the oxygen molecule into two oxygen atoms is about $5.15\textrm{eV}$, which corresponds to a wavelength of about $240\textrm{nm}$. So starting at this energy we see a broad absorption where photons of increasing energy are absorbed to produce oxygen atoms with increasing kinetic energy.