# Why does "Vacuum UV" start at 200nm?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, wavelength, molecules

According to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet#Subtypes) Vacuum UV is UV light with a wavelength of less then 200nm.

I've been told [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/772225/263465) that the reason why thoses ranges of UV are strongly absorbed by the air is that those photons have enough energy to break apart the molecular bonds of $\rm O_2$ molecules. However the bond energy of $\rm O_2$ is 5.15 ev. which corresponds to a wavelength of 240nm, not 200nm. What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: Absorption isn't an all-or-nothing proposition. Yes, some starts around 240nm, but by 200nm multiple processes are contributing and the cross-section has gone up. Plus, 200 is a nice round number that is easy to remember.